# Как зайти в графическую оболочку в linux?

Tags: linux, gnome

Установил только что Debian 9.3 с графической оболочкой Gnome. При установке не создавал пользователей, предполагая вход под рутом. Но в графическом окне входа в систему не могу зайти под рутом, получаю сообщение "Не сработало. Попробуйте еще раз". Тогда захожу в консоль, создаю пользователя и уже под ним снова пытаюсь зайти в графическом окне. Но получаю то же сообщение. Что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вводите неправильный пароль, видимо.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Проблема оказалась в том, что при создании нового пользователя не создавалась домашняя директория пользователя.

Comment: ну так удобнее ж пользоваться дистрибутивной «обёрткой»: `adduser имя`. и не надо «мудрить» с опциями (для *useradd*) — будет создан полноценный пользователь, и с домашним каталогом, и с паролем.